# R710 with ESXi 6.5 and PERC 6/E - How to update drivers?

Tags: vmware-esxi, windows-server-2016, drivers

- R710
- PERC 6/E
- Raid 6
- Running a Windows server 2016 and Unitrends in virtual machines in
  ESXi.

So I have a Raid 6 array and need to expand the array. OMSA tells me I have an out of date driver. I have 6.3.0-0001 and 6.3.3-0002 (the latest driver) is required. I've not updated a server like this before now so I need a bit of help.

First off, I have the choice of Linux or Windows drivers. I am running the free version of ESXi 6.5 so I am confused about which driver I need.

Second, just exactly does one go about installing these drivers once the right drivers are downloaded? I have connected to iDRAC via the web interface and have tried to install both the EXE and BIN. Both get to 96% uploaded and then fail.

I have seen that there is a SUU that can be uploaded and then one can put together repositories and use those. IS that the right way? If so the only choices I have is Linux and Windows - same question, which one?

There ARE choices (no SUU) for ESXi 6.0 but no 6.5.

Bottom line is I am very confused about how to get drivers up to date so I can expand my raid.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the SUU, it will run off a bootable USB stick and would update everything. The process take minimum 30/45m

I did it multiple time.

On newer Dell server I managed to do it via the iDRAC, but in the x30 series, not on a older x10 serie like in your case.

Comment: I take it that the SUU runs stand alone from the USB drive so Linux or Windows is an OS that runs temporarily in order to install the drivers? So it does not matter which OS I choose as long as I am comfortable with that choice for the duration of the installation or the drivers? IN other works the SUU OS choice has nothing to do with what is actually already installed on the server?

Comment: I am certainly not correct. I just found this on Dell's page about SUU: "As the SUU is operating system specific and in order to successfully update drivers, please select the version matching your operating system. The latest version of the SUU can be found in the "Drivers & Downloads" page of your support product page." If I am running ESXi will Linux or Windows work?

Comment: The SUU iso create a Linux bootable disk, so when it boot it dont care what your OS is, and it run the update( see there (https://www.dell.com/support/article/ca/en/cabsdt1/sln296511/updating-dell-poweredge-servers-via-bootable-media-iso?lang=en)

Comment: Unfortunately, that applies to generation 12 -14. The R710 is gen 11 and is not listed on that page.

Comment: related; https://serverfault.com/questions/693510/how-to-update-a-dell-server-when-the-dell-server-update-utility-iso-is-11gb

Answer (score 0):

First off that update is a firmware update. Second the server will at least need to be rebooted to do the update.

We have the T610 (lower spec same generation) Dell server. You can use the Dell Update Package (DUP) marked with DUP and windows and 32 bit exe on the dell site and upload it directly in the iDRAC interface to be installed at the next reboot. If the exe on the Dell page does not say DUP it is not suitable for use in the iDRAC.

The iDRAC is its own computer, running its own OS, separate from whatever you have installed on the rest of the system, in your case ESXi. In that generation machine iDRAC seems to be running 32 bit windows.