# Does OS matter when creating iso using Dell Repository Manager?

Tags: dell-poweredge

When creating a firmware update SUU iso using Dell's Repository Manager does the selection of the OS matter? It is not clear to me if the DUP OS selection has to do with the target OS that is installed on the Dell server or is this the OS that runs temporarily while it is installing firmware?

Is it the same result regardless of OS selected?

Another way to ask...if I have ESXi as my hypervisor then does it matter what OS I select for the DUP format I select?

[Dell Repository Manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5gIC.jpg)

Comment: Related to that question; https://serverfault.com/questions/948352/r710-with-esxi-6-5-and-perc-6-e-how-to-update-drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firmwares are OS independent, maybe with the exception of the  ***OS Driver Pack***

> OS Driver Pack for PowerEdge 14G servers. This driver pack contains
>   applicable storage, NIC, and video drivers to support OS installation
>   using Unified Server Configurator - Lifecycle Controller Enabled

The reason why SBUU has an OS selection is for **Server Operating System Installation** (SOI) module in SBUU which will (optionally) proceed with the OS install after firmware updates:

> The Server Operating System Installation (SOI) module in SBUU enables
>   you to install Dell-supported operating systems on your Dell systems.
>   SOI also maps the operating system you want to install on your system
>   and installs the requisite drivers. It has a simple interface to
>   configure Dell-supported storage controllers.

See https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln285675/server-operating-system-installation-using-system-build-and-update-utility-sbuu-?lang=en